# Specified version in @WSDLDocumentation value

Tags: java, annotations, wsdl, cxf, constants

I'm trying to put a dynamic value on the constant of WSDLDocumentation annoation.

Something like that :

```
static final ResourceBundle bundleConfigApplication = ResourceBundle.getBundle("contract");
static final String VERSION = bundleConfigApplication.getString("affilie.version");

@WSDLDocumentation(value = VERSION, placement = WSDLDocumentation.Placement.TOP)
```

**The main goal here, is to have a configurable value in the WSDL documentation.**

The problem is, annotation value is a constant and constant doesn't accept variable...

If someone have any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i think i found a way to do this with javaassist : http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.fr/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html